# Save coordinates in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to find the user coordinates, but I don't know how to save them in a database. This is a critical step for a form I am creating. I really appreciate your help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Geolocation </title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "area-nav">
            <div> <h2> Ask the browser for location permissions </h2> </div>
            <button id = "request"> Request browser geolocation permissions </button>
            <div> by browser </div>
            <div id = "nlat"> </div>
            <div id = "nlon"> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $ (document) .ready (function () {
            // Click the button to request permissions
            $ ("# request"). click (function () {
                // If the browser supports geolocation
                if (!! navigator.geolocation) {
                    // We request geolocation data from the browser
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
                            // If the browser delivers the geolocation data we print it
                            function (position) {
                                window.alert ("nav allowed");
                                $ ("# nlat"). text (position.coords.latitude);
                                $ ("# nlon"). text (position.coords.longitude);
                            },
                            // If you don't deliver them, send an error alert
                            function () {
                                window.alert ("nav not allowed");
                            }
                    );
                }
            });

        });



    </script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to post the coordinates data.

```
$.post("save-coordinates.php",
  {
    lat: position.coords.latitude),
    long: position.coords.longitude)
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp